# c++ Что быстрее будет работать, эллипсис с va_list или шаблонные функции с parameter-pack?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-функций

Вопрос в заголовке. Насколько я знаю, эллипсис (то самое `...`) не создает новые инстанции (перегрузки) функции, в отличие от шаблонов, где функция в памяти будет дублироваться в зависимости от количества аргументов, так ли это?

Comment: В принципе да, но при этом возможности для оптимизации выше, так что что именно будет **быстрее** — далеко не факт. Я бы как раз при прочих равных поставил на шаблоны...

Comment: Тут стоило бы начать с того, что `...` не позволяет передавать аргументы произвольных типов, а шаблонная функция позволяет.